# Strange behavior with window.scroll function and removing classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I do have a strange problem with my jquery script on the following site: http://www.zugestellt.com

When I scroll down or up, the current area is highlighted correctly in menu (added class "current-menu-item").

Now the strange thing:
If I choose a menu item by click the class "current-menu-item" isn't deleted anymore from the menu item that I clicked.

Here is my code:

```
(function($){

var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#header #menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() + 15,
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        href = '.scroll-' + href.replace('/#','').toLowerCase();
        var item = $( $(href) );
        if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

    menuItems.parents('li').removeClass("current-menu-item");

$(document).on('click', "#header #menu a" ,function(e) {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    href = '.scroll-' + href.replace('/#','').toLowerCase();
    var offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top - topMenuHeight + 1;

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: offsetTop
    }, 300);

    e.preventDefault();

});


$(window).scroll(function(){

    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight;
    var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
        if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
        return this;
    });

    cur = cur[cur.length-1];

    var id = '';
    if(cur && cur.length) {

        id =  $.grep(cur[0].className.split(" "), function(v, i){
            return v.indexOf('scroll-') === 0;
        }).join();

    }

    if (lastId !== id) {
        lastId = id;

        var new_url = id.replace('scroll-','/#');

        menuItems
            .parents('li')
            .removeClass("current-menu-item")
            .end()
            .filter('a[href*="' + new_url + '"]')
            .parents('li')
            .addClass("current-menu-item");
    }

});

})(jQuery);
```

Now,if you are wondering why I don't work with hashes to choose the right section, this is a template from themeforest and the sitebuilder from this theme doesn't allow to add ids but classes.

Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Is this code from your theme? right? or its your own code?

Comment: no that's a custom code i wrote, because this functionality isn't available in the theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you click again on menu it add .sfHover class .. So you need to remove it as well .. try this

```
menuItems
   .parents('li')
   .removeClass("current-menu-item")
   .removeClass("sfHover")
   .end()
   .filter('a[href*="' + new_url + '"]')
   .parents('li')
   .addClass("current-menu-item");
```

Comment: @themca  Good Luck :)